# React state update step behind

Tags: reactjs, state

This color picker works but one step behind. I've been using React 15.4.2. 
Is it an issue to be fixed in later versions?
In case it's my fault, please, how to master "pending state condition"?
Pen http://codepen.io/462960/pen/qrBLje
Code:

```
let Input =  React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
        return {
        today_color: "#E5D380"
    };
    },
  colorChange(e){
        this.setState({
            today_color: e.target.value
        })
        document.querySelector('html').style.setProperty('--base', this.state.today_color);
     },
  render(){
    return (<div>
           <input className="today_color" onChange={this.colorChange} type="color" defaultValue={this.state.today_color}/>
           </div>)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is that once you call setState the component rerenders and this code isn't called again:

```
document.querySelector('html').style.setProperty('--base', this.state.today_color);
```

And the first time it is called, `this.state.today_color` is still the previous value.

What you should do is the following:

```
this.setState({
  today_color: e.target.value
}, () => document.querySelector('html').style.setProperty('--base', this.state.today_color));
```

This makes sure the setProperty gets called after setState is done and after you have the correct value in your state.

Edit: here's a working [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJvNMX).

Comment: So did I, @paqash, that's why I was a bit surprised by your request and, taking into account the rules, showed my appreciation in such way. One of those two arrows up is from me.

Comment: Yes, but upvoting is not the same as accepting an answer... https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: My fault, @paqash. Your answer is fulfilling.